# Saving score at checkpoint

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a 3D BMX sidescroller with a trick system and points. I've all ready got check points in for when you crash and they work well. The problem I'm having is when you crash your score doesn't go back to what it was when you first passed the checkpoint, meaning people can just get a high score by doing a really big trick and crashing over and over again. Every tutorial, and I mean literally every one, has been about saving a high score at the end of a level. Here's the relevant script

```
private float flipScore;
private float spinScore;

void FixedUpdate()

if (!IsGrounded())
        
            flipScore += (transform.localEulerAngles.x) * Time.deltaTime * 0.5f;
            spinScore += transform.localEulerAngles.y * Time.deltaTime * 1f;
```

An example for anyone who needs extra clarification.
You reach the first checkpoint with 12345 points. You do a few tricks to get up to 15000 but crash before the next checkpoint then you start back at the first checkpoint with 12345 points.

I've tried pretty much everything I've seen in the tutorials but to no avail.

Comment: You could store the current points when you reach a checkpoint.  When resetting to a checkpoint, reset the points to the value set when you hit the checkpoint.

Comment: Any idea how I one would go about this? Like what code/functions/methods/whatever would be used?

Comment: @hijinxbassist just explained how you'd go about this.  If you don't know how to turn that logic into code, you might be better starting off with a basic coding tutorial.  Then, try to solve the problem yourself, and if you have issues with your attempt, post them here and we can try to help.

Comment: Could you make your example code one that would compile?

Comment: That's what I was hoping for derHugo. I know what needs to be done, storing the points at a checkpoint is obvious, it's the how I need help with.

Answer (score 1):

Store the points when you reach a checkpoint.
When resetting to the checkpoint, set the score to what was stored.

```
private float checkpointSpinScore;
private float checkpointFlipScore;

private void OnCheckpointReached()
{
    checkpointSpinScore = spinScore;
    checkpointFlipScore = flipScore;
}
private void OnResetToCheckpoint()
{
    spinScore = checkpointSpinScore;
    flipScore = checkpointFlipScore;
}
```